# Move Object in its own X - axis to and from, on mouse drag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

I want to:

1. move a particular object in its own X- axis to and from, by using mouse.
2. Clamp the movement between that box gap

Code i tried but not working for me:

```
    void Update()
    {
    point = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(
    new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x,
            (transform.position.y-Camera.main.transform.position.y),
            (transform.position.z-Camera.main.transform.position.z)));

    point.y = transform.position.y;                   
    point.z = transform.position.z;
    transform.position = point;
  }
```

Comment: In what language and platform? Please tag appropriately

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?  Please show us your code! StackOverflow is not ment to be a `Please code that for me` plattform but rather a community providing help with specific programming issues. Please look at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to write a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) When you have a specific coding related problem we are glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

To clamp a value you can use the `Mathf.Clamp()` method.

The full solution could look something like this:

Add a script to your lever object:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class MoveOnMouseDrag : MonoBehaviour {

    public float halfDistance;

    void Start()
    {
        EventTrigger trigger = GetComponent<EventTrigger>();
        EventTrigger.Entry entry = new EventTrigger.Entry();
        entry.eventID = EventTriggerType.Drag;
        entry.callback.AddListener((data) => { OnDragDelegate((PointerEventData)data); });
        trigger.triggers.Add(entry);
    }

    public void OnDragDelegate(PointerEventData data)
    {
        float distanceFromCamera = Vector3.Distance(Camera.main.transform.position, transform.position);
        var newPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(data.position.x, data.position.y, distanceFromCamera));

        transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(newPos.x, -halfDistance, halfDistance),
                                         transform.position.y,
                                         transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

In order for the script to work you have to add `EventTrigger` component to the same object, `EventSystem` to the scene and `PhysicsRaycaster` component to the camera.